# get key from a two dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having a two-dimensional array like this

```
 $data = Array
  (
   [1] => Array
    (
        [type] => Combine
        [aggregator] => all
        [value] => 1
        [new_child] => 
    )

    [1--1] => Array
    (
        [type] => Product
        [attribute] => seller_id
        [operator] => ==
        [value] => 1
    )

   [1--2] => Array
    (
        [type] => SProduct
        [attribute] => seller_id
        [operator] => ==
        [value] => 1
    )

)
```

I need to unset the array which contains the seller_id. Anyone provide me the code snippet?

I have tried below code

```
<?php
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
            if(in_array('seller_id',$value)){
                array_keys($value);
            }
        }
```

But using this i'm not getting keys

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: edit your question and add what you have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`unset()`](http://php.net/unset), and iterate over the array using key :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($value['attribute']) && $value['attribute'] == 'seller_id') {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following to unset key in the array

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($value['attribute'])) {
        if($value['attribute']=='seller_id'){
            unset($array[$key];
        }
    }
}
```